# hide off canvas menu helix3

Tags: module, helix3

am using helix3 template and I need to hide the "off canvas menu" on large screens and make it appears only on tablets and mobile screens.
any help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First go to:

- **Extensions** > **Templates** > **Your Helix Template** > **Menu** Tab

From here select in the option **Menu Type** only **Mega Menu**, this option hide the 
off canvas menu on large screens.

Now for display the off canvas menu in tablet go to this path:

- **your_site.com/templates/helix_template/features/menu.php**

Find this line:

```
<a id="offcanvas-toggler" class="visible-xs" href="#"><i class="fa fa-bars"></i></a>
```

And add the values **visible-sm** and **visible-md**:

```
<a id="offcanvas-toggler" class="visible-xs visible-sm visible-md" href="#"><i class="fa fa-bars"></i></a>
```

Regards.

Answer (score 1):

quick solution-

```
@media (min-width: 1600px) {
  .offcanvas-menu, #offcanvas-toggler {display:none;}
}
```

Just add this to the custom css code.

Answer (score 0):

There is an easier way.
Go to Templates > Style > Shaper_helix3  > Menu > Menu Type and choose: Mega Menu
Save and  thats it!

Answer (score 0):

Go to template->**templateDetails.xml** comment out or remove position offcanvas from  .
Now go to root directory then **features** and edit file **menu.php** and comment/remove the following lines.

save and exit.
Now reload your pages.

Comment: It seems that you have forgotten to put some lines of code from "menu.php" file.